# CSS - How to prevent opening both left and right sidebar?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner of HTML and CSS. I am learning web development recently and trying to make a simple website page. On that page, there will be two sidebars. One is left side bar, other one  is right side bar. But when i click on left sidebar menu icon, it opens both left and right sidebar, but i want to open only left one. And when i click on right sidebar menu icon, it only opens right sidebar. What am i doing wrong here ?

```css
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: tahoma;
}

body {
  background-image: url(scene.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.header {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #000000;
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}

.main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.mainInner {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebarMenu {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  transform: translateX(-250px);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #000000 0%, #3f5efb 100%);
}

.rightsidebarMenu {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  transform: translateX(250px);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #000000 0%, #3f5efb 100%);
}

.sidebarMenuInner {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.10);
}

.rightsidebarMenuInner {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.10);
}

.sidebarMenuInner li {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.10);
}

.rightsidebarMenuInner li {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.10);
}

.sidebarMenuInner li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border: 2px;
}

.rightsidebarMenuInner li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border: 2px;
}

.sidebarMenuInner li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.50);
}

.rightsidebarMenuInner li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.50);
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.sidebarMenu {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.rightsidebarMenu {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.sidebarIconToggle {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 22px;
  left: 35px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}

.rightsidebarIconToggle {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 22px;
  right: 35px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}

.spinner {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.right.spinner {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.right.horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.diagonal.part-1 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.right.diagonal.part-1 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.right.diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.sidebarIconToggle>.horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.sidebarIconToggle>.diagonal.part-1 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  margin-top: 8px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.sidebarIconToggle>.diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  margin-top: -8px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.rightsidebarIconToggle>.right.horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.rightsidebarIconToggle>.right.diagonal.part-1 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  margin-top: 8px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.rightsidebarIconToggle>.right.diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu">
<label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
     <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
     <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
     <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
    
     </label>


<div class="sidebarMenu">
  <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
    <li>Munem Sohan <span>Web Developer</span></li>
    <li><span>Company</span></li>
    <li><span>Facebook</span></li>
    <li><span>Twitter</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<input type="checkbox" class="rightopenSidebarMenu" id="rightopenSidebarMenu">
<label for="rightopenSidebarMenu" class="rightsidebarIconToggle">
     <div class="right spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
     <div class="right spinner horizontal"></div>
     <div class="right spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
    
     </label>


<div class="rightsidebarMenu">
  <ul class="rightsidebarMenuInner">
    <li>Sohan <span>Web Developer</span></li>
    <li><span>Sabbir</span></li>
    <li><span>Sumi</span></li>
    <li><span>Shovon</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: Left sidebar click, both sidebar open]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add id with checkbox, so it can apply checkbox uniquely for opening toggle

```css
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: tahoma;
}

body {
  background-image: url(scene.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.header {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #000000;
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}

.main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.mainInner {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebarMenu {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  transform: translateX(-250px);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #000000 0%, #3f5efb 100%);
}

.rightsidebarMenu {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  transform: translateX(250px);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #000000 0%, #3f5efb 100%);
}

.sidebarMenuInner {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.10);
}

.rightsidebarMenuInner {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.10);
}

.sidebarMenuInner li {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.10);
}

.rightsidebarMenuInner li {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.10);
}

.sidebarMenuInner li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border: 2px;
}

.rightsidebarMenuInner li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border: 2px;
}

.sidebarMenuInner li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.50);
}

.rightsidebarMenuInner li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.50);
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]#openSidebarMenu:checked~.sidebarMenu {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

input[type="checkbox"]#rightopenSidebarMenu:checked~.rightsidebarMenu {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.sidebarIconToggle {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 22px;
  left: 35px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}

.rightsidebarIconToggle {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 22px;
  right: 35px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}

.spinner {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.right.spinner {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.right.horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.diagonal.part-1 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.right.diagonal.part-1 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.right.diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]#openSidebarMenu:checked~.sidebarIconToggle>.horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]#openSidebarMenu:checked~.sidebarIconToggle>.diagonal.part-1 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  margin-top: 8px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]#openSidebarMenu:checked~.sidebarIconToggle>.diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  margin-top: -8px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]#rightopenSidebarMenu:checked~.rightsidebarIconToggle>.right.horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]#rightopenSidebarMenu:checked~.rightsidebarIconToggle>.right.diagonal.part-1 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  margin-top: 8px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]#rightopenSidebarMenu:checked~.rightsidebarIconToggle>.right.diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu">
<label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
     <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
     <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
     <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
    
     </label>


<div class="sidebarMenu">
  <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
    <li>Munem Sohan <span>Web Developer</span></li>
    <li><span>Company</span></li>
    <li><span>Facebook</span></li>
    <li><span>Twitter</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<input type="checkbox" class="rightopenSidebarMenu" id="rightopenSidebarMenu">
<label for="rightopenSidebarMenu" class="rightsidebarIconToggle">
     <div class="right spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
     <div class="right spinner horizontal"></div>
     <div class="right spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
    
     </label>


<div class="rightsidebarMenu">
  <ul class="rightsidebarMenuInner">
    <li>Sohan <span>Web Developer</span></li>
    <li><span>Sabbir</span></li>
    <li><span>Sumi</span></li>
    <li><span>Shovon</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```